# How to solve [K]{U}={F} FEM where some values of {U} are known.

Tags: boundary-value-problem, finite-element-method, poissons-equation

I am  trying to solve the 2D-Poisson equation using the FEM. I have created the global stiffness matrix and I know my boundary conditions. I am looking at $0<x<4$ and $0<y<2$ with boundary conditions U(0,y) = 100, U(4,y) = 250, U(x,0) = 50, U(x,2) = 200. I am using square Elements (8 of them) broken at each integer. So i know all the U-values except for U6,U7,U8 (the values inside the domain, not on the boundary). How do I solve for these? Also, since it is the poisson equation {F} = {0.0}. Hopefully it will help to note that there are 15 values of U, 12 of which are known due to boundary conditions.

Answer (score 1):

Adapted from this [lecture notes](http://www.asc.tuwien.ac.at/~schoeberl/wiki/lva/notes/numpde.pdf) page 9.

The approach splits the matrix and right-hand side into Dirichlet and free nodes:
$$
K =
\begin{pmatrix}
K_{DD} & K_{Df} \\
K_{fD} & K_{ff}
\end{pmatrix}
\qquad
F =
\begin{pmatrix}
F_D \\
F_f
\end{pmatrix}
$$

In your case the free nodes have the indices $\{6, 7, 8\}$.
With $N$ the total number of nodes ($N = 15$ in your case) the system of linear equations for $U = (U_i) \in \mathbb{R}^N, U=(U_D, U_f)$ is then:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
I & 0 \\
K_{fD} & K_{ff}
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
U_D \\
U_f
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
U_D \\
F_f
\end{pmatrix}
$$

From the second row of the equation you get:
$$K_{fD} U_D + K_{ff} U_f = F_f$$

Bringing the unknowns on one side and $F_f = 0$:
$$U_f = - K_{ff}^{-1} K_{fD} U_D$$

Comment: Bernard, What would K_fd be? If I am not mistaken, K_ff would be a 3x3 matrix created from the 6-8 rows and columns of K? Would then I not have a mismatch of dimension in the matrix multiplication of the last equation?

Comment: You are right with K_ff. For K_fD the row indices are 6-8 and the column (Dirichlet) indices are the complement of that (0-5, 9-14). So that's a 3x12 matrix. And U_D are the Dirichlet entries of the solution which are prescribed for the indices 0-5, 9-14. So it's a vector with 12 entries. Thus the dimensions match in the last equation.